# What number system should the buffer be in?

Tags: arrays, tcp, connection, byte, buffer

I want to send an array of bytes by creating it myself, not by string encoding. What number system should this array be in, or does it make no difference?

Comment: If you want/need an array of bytes, use an array of bytes. No need for any number system.

Answer (score 0):

A byte is a byte (with a decimal value from 0 to 255). It has no inherent meaning. A byte with a decimal value of 97 could be represented as:

- 97 (decimal)
- 0x61 (hex)
- 'a' (ASCII)
- 0110 0001 (binary)

or any other format that two people mutually agree to. The value will always be the same.

So, to answer your question, no, the actual format itself does not make a difference.